# German entry visa

Tags: germany, working-visas, italy

I am currently holding a researcher permit in Italy with non-EU passport, now I will move to Germany to take up another researcher position.

Is it possible to directly apply for the residence permit at auslanderbehorde for that specific city without obtaining entry visa from German embassy in Rome?

**What I understand so far:** Yes, I can do that however I must have *permanent residence card* of Italy.

Can someone let me know if there is a way, I can directly register at auslanderbehorde?

Comment: Are you a citizen of the US, Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, or South Korea?

Comment: No, I does not belong to one of the above mentioned countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal process is that such an application is made at a consulate, which they then send on to the responsible Ausländerbehörde for approval, afterwhich the visa is issued.

So I am not sure what benifit you wish to achieve by bypassing the standard procedure, since you don't have a *permanent residence card* of Italy - but a researcher permit.

I assume with this term (*permanent residence card*) you mean an [EU long-term residence permit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0146), where this would then be possible. Otherwise you must go through the standard procedures.

---

**Sources**:

- [Section 9a (AufenthG) - EU long-term residence permit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0146)

Comment: Citizens of the US, Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, and South Korea, however, do not need a visa.  They can apply for the residence permit in Germany: https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/residence-visa/922288

Comment: Members of the family of an EU citizen should be able to apply for a residence card directly as well. It would be useful to have an answer listing the various exceptions.

Comment: The benefits are obvious to anybody who actually experienced the standard procedure: less paperwork, one less fee to pay, not losing time before you can start getting set up, no need to balance unpredictable consulate response times and travel schedule. On the other hand, if you have the right long-stay visa, you would be allowed to start working immediately upon landing in Germany, which is not the case for US, etc. citizens applying for a permit directly.

Comment: @Relaxed Also a local consulate will be more familiar with local documents being submitted and thus bring into a form that the Ausländerbehörde will understand. A family member of an EU citizen would not need an Italian researcher permit, so that aspect was not handled and since no citizenship was given those exceptions either. The answer concentrates on where the idea that with a *permanent residence card* a direct application is possible (which is the core of the question).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Which documents would that be? You still need to apply for a residence permit no matter what. Does having a visa exempts you from submitting some documents when you do that?

Comment: @Relaxed A (German) consulate, which is familiar with the local country, will verify that the document is authentic and equivalent to what ever is required. The local Authority will accept that varification, since they *may* have no experience in how Certificate X from country Y may look like. When the visa is issued, the application process has been completed since the needed documents were submitted with the application. After arrival the only thing that needs to be done is to issue the residence permit.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That doesn't really answer my question. Clearly, applying for a residence permit is a distinct procedure, what the consulate may or may not do isn't the question. How does the application for a residence permit differ when you have a visa vs. not have a visa? Does the *Ausländerbehörde* conduct more thorough verifications for applicants who do not have a visa? Does it require more documents from these applicants? Does it contact consulates if there hasn't been a prior verification?

Comment: @Relaxed That is more difficult to explain since the internal instructions of the State (Länder) Ausländerbehörde are not published (as apposed to those of the consulate that are). My personal knowledge, based on experience of US citizens that went through the process, is now outdated. Previously they received initially a 3 months permit, that would then be renewed for 1 year. The present procedure is probably different, but a quick search brought no practical experience. Sorry.